# jenkins URL with computer name does not open page

Tags: jenkins

I know this question is asked before but I could not find any right solution for that

I have install jenkins on my windows 7 as windows service, it works fine with default URL `localhost:8080`, but when I set `//mycomputerName:8080` in configuration system- jenkins location and then save it and restarted jenkins and enter `//mycomputerName:8080` in browser address jenking will not open. I have done the same installation on my laptop windows 7 without any problem, but on my desktop I have installed, uninstalled several times with the same problem.

Comment: Did you read the answers to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221238?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Jenkins URL" means in configuration settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221238/what-does-jenkins-url-means-in-configuration-settings)

Comment: Oli thanks for your response, yes I read this answer but it is not really solution or it did not say how to fix it, I know that I have to go to manage jenkins--configuration system then in the jenkins location put the jenkins URL in the text box, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Thanks Hamid, what do you mean by configuration setting, are you talking about configure system or config.xml file anyway I did not see any duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my question above many people have asked this question and had the same problem but all answer have been something from jenkins documentation and actually not solution.
so finally I found the problem and  write it here probably  for some people with the same problem

first I uninstalled jenkins removed all files, folder and everything related to jenking also from windows registry and installed jenking but did not work.
reinstalled windows (upgrade) and installed jenking again but did not work.
next I clean reinstalled windows and installed jenkins and in this case jenkins works as I expected but I do not know what was wrong with the windows.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to give my solution

1. Go to Jenkins Home Directory ( I have mine in C:\Jenkins)
2. Edit jenkins.xml
3. Add this `--prefix=/jenkins` to the end of the argument as show below and restart the jenkins service ALL worked OK for me !

Example :
 `<arguments>-Xrs-Xmx256mDhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins</arguments>`

4. Open Url `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`  this should bring up the home page of jenkins

Comment: In addition, double quotes were also required as `--prefix="/jenkins"`

Answer (score 0):

Add to Vamshi's answer. Instead of the config in the

`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\config.xml` (you won't find `<argument>` in this file)

add the `--prefix=\jenkins` to the `<argument>` in `jenkins.xml`

`C:\Program Files\Jenkins` and restart the service.