# Change Jenkins basepath

Tags: nginx, jenkins, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to serve a stock jenkins installation (on Amazon Linux AMI) thru myjenkinsinstance:8080/jenkins (rather than myjenkinsinstance:8080), and then proxy this with e.g. Nginx (over HTTP).

This question has been 'answered' before, but the solution doesn't seem to be relevant anymore.

@admins I would prefer to comment on that thread (specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521495/5657321) 'answer'), rather than opening a duplicate, but I am not allowed to, per my 'reputation' score (as my comment would not be a solution at all, but further request for help).

From the closest thing to an answer I've seen:

> 1. Go to Jenkins Home Directory ( I have mine in C:\Jenkins)
> 2. Edit jenkins.xml
> 3. Add this `--prefix=/jenkins` to the end of the argument as show below and restart the jenkins service ALL worked OK for me !
>
> Example :  `<arguments>-Xrs-Xmx256mDhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --prefix=/jenkins</arguments>`
>
> 4. Open Url http://localhost:8080/jenkins this should bring up the home page of jenkins

- there is no 'jenkins.xml' in the $JENKINS_HOME directory, but there is a config.xml
- there is no `<arguments/>` entry in the config.xml
- there seems to be no other configuration for the initial installation

There's also a 'Jenkins Location > Jenkins URL' setting in the "Configure System" settings (myjenkinsinstance/configure), but modifying this seems to have no noticeable affect.

The end goal would be to automate this installation via e.g. CloudFormation (as part of the EC2's UserData).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer you found seems to be about configuring a Windows service which runs Jenkins. `jenkins.xml` file is a config file for the service with java path, env vars, and arguments. In your case it's Linux so depending on how you installed your Jenkins you need to pass the same `--prefix` arg in you init script or systemd unit or whatever you have.

Answer (score 0):

On your linux system, you need to find the jenkins default config file located at

> /etc/default/jenkins

and then add the following arguments according to your requirements. This is a rough idea.

> JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --prefix=/jenkins
>   --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --ajp13Port=$AJP_PORT"

This should work most likely. If it doesnt, pls update your answer with the current arguments present. This works fine for Debian/Ubuntu.

Also you are running jenkins on your windows machine or linux?

Comment: JENKINS_ARGS=" --prefix=/jenkins" is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't seem to have that file/directory

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-193 ~]$ ls /etc/default/

nss  useradd`

Comment: Sorry for the crappy format above, apparently @stackoverflow, they don't respect newlines

Comment: btw, this is linux (from the Amazon Linux AMI, which I believe is an offshoot of RHEL 5 and 6 apparently?)

Answer (score 0):

So my 'solution' was to use sed and insert some lines into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/init.d/jenkins.

e.g.

- `sed -i '/^        location \/ {/aproxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:8080/;' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
- `sed -i '/^PARAMS=/ s/"$/ --prefix=\/jenkins"/' /etc/init.d/jenkins`

I highly doubt this is anything near a 'best practice', but it seems to work for now (what happens were I to update with yum... I'm not sure, but the plan is to back the instance with an Elastic Filesystem, which hopefully will allow us to consider the jenkins instance ephemeral, anyway).