# Where to set Jenkins root URL in the GUI?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is giving me a warning:

> Jenkins root URL is empty but is required for the proper operation of
>   many Jenkins features like email notifications, PR status update, and
>   environment variables such as BUILD_URL. Please provide an accurate
>   value in Jenkins configuration.

The link to Jenkins configuration is /configure, but there is no "Root URL" field there. Where can this be set?

Comment: In Jenkins 2.150 the Jenkins root URL is defined by the *Jenkins URL* item in the **Jenkins Location** section of the `/configure` page

Comment: Kind of made you wish that the alert and the actual setting naming should match. Also, in my case, actually setting "Jenkins URL" does not make the alert go away, so there is something fishy going on. 

Comment: @Jonny I had to set the administrator email address in the Location section to make it go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is located in **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Jenkins Location**.

Note: if you want to change Jenkins URL, I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222167/10721592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29217065/10721592) answers first.

Answer (score -1):

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Serve resource files from another domain -> Resource root URL